# Multiple DNS servers chained

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, vps, internal-dns

I have 3 small VPS instances in the web, and I want to improve the routing between them. These  servers are used for some private things and one of them is for hosting websites.
My problem is that the service provider does not provide a proper interface to manage DNS entries, which means, that my domain name points to only one server. I can't say that I want sub.doma.in point to one of my other servers, only that the domain points to that single VPS where my website is hosted.

Can I setup a DNS server on the VPS where the DNS of the provider is pointing my domain too? Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask your provider or domain registrar to change or create **`NS`** entries for your domain pointing to the IP's of your VPS servers (**`asdasd.com. IN NS 123.123.123.123`**), where you can setup DNS for your domain. This way, all domain-related requests will go to your VPS DNS service and you'll be able to setup anything related to forward DNS zone.

Comment: what if, the provider points to my webserver like `*.whatever.com` wouldn't that mean that every request is pointing to my server, and i can route wherever I want? Just out of curiosity. I didn't test it yet, by the way.

Comment: it depends on which type of entry it will be, in case of NS - yes, in case of A - no, you can do whatever you want. ask to add NS entries with each of your servers running DNS service.